# NSView frame and setContentBorderThickness:forEdge:

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I have a window, which I set `setContentBorderThickness:42 forEdge:NSMinYEdge`.

Now, when I do `[[window contentSize] frame]` it still shows the dimensions of the window (minus the top bar with title and buttons), but it wont subtract the 42 of the border thickness.

Please, how do I get the proper dimensions of the empty area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use not `contentSize` but `contentView`. And if You use 42 pixels height BorderThickness than just subtract that height from Your window view's height like this:

```
NSRect windowFrame = [[window contentView] frame];

windowFrame.size.height = windowFrame.size.height - [window contentBorderThicknessForEdge:NSMinYEdge];

NSLog(@"TRUE height: %f",windowFrame.size.height);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to subtracts it automatically? Alternatively, this 42 - where do I get it from, apart from remembering what I set in `setContentBorderThickness`? I mean, is there any getter, instance variable, ...  where is it stored?

Comment: Yes, to get automaticaly height You can do it like this: `[window contentBorderThicknessForEdge:NSMinYEdge]`, look at updated code.